# Flutter: iOS Emulator for Windows / Linux to run Flutter Applications?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, kotlin, flutter-web

I have started learning Flutter for the past few months. Is there any way to use iOS simulators on Windows/Linux?

I have come across a wonderful package named [device_preview](https://pub.dev/packages/device_preview) which is used to **Preview any device from any device** and change the orientations.

What are the other methods available to emulate an iOS device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, in my opinion, there are no simply and professional ways to use iOS/iPadOS simulators on Windows (there are some online services but you need to pay them).

You can use packages like `device_preview` in order to test the correct aspect ratio and size but you cannot use the native APIs.

The best way to emulate iOS is to use iOS simulator on a Mac but sometimes you will need also a real iOS device because, different from Android simulators, iOS simulators does not replicate perfectly the real iOS features.